# Manipulating SVG-files with python

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

Is it possible to manipulate existing svg files in python? I know the `svgwrite` package but it only creates new svg files... I just want to add 3 numbers to an existing svg file. It should be only an update showing the old svg file with these 3 new numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As with other text files, you need to read the file to memory, modify and then write the modified file to disk.